# content getDistributedNodes array in firefox/chrome but NodeList in canary

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, polymer

I'm checking out Polymer right now. It has some amasing features.
I have a custom element that accesses some distributed nodes, using `getDistributedNodes`.
in chrome and firefox `getDistributedNodes` returns an array, rather than a `NodeList`, but in chrome canary I get a `NodeList`.

without Polymer (much simpler example using only shadowDom and no custom elements) I get NodeList in both chrome stable and chrome canary.

Which one of these is supposed to be the correct return value, and what causes this?

[here is a jsfiddle with Polymer](http://jsfiddle.net/gqJ4v/3/)

[and without Polymer, no custom element, works only with native shadowDom support, so no firefox)](http://jsfiddle.net/mvVeu/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in Chrome (stable) and other browsers, Polymer uses the Shadow DOM polyfill, which wraps DOM objects. You can't create a `NodeList` natively, so the call mimics the native API best it can by returning an Array.

Under Canary (with "Experimental Web Platform features" on in about:flags"), Polymer will use native Shadow DOM. The reason is that Canary has many new Shadow DOM features/fixes/perf optimizations that haven't made their way to the stable channel yet. We're aggressively forcing the polyfill until it hits stable :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I saw that there was native shadow dom in chrome but I guess it's not usable yet.